# What is the equation for a solid torus?

Tags: geometry, surfaces

I know that the equation for a torus is given by
$$\left(R - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 = r^2$$

where $R$ is the larger radius and the $r$ is the smaller radius. Now I was reading about the [solid torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_torus), which can be constructed by forming a cartesian product of a disc in $D^2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a circle $S^1$. Suppose for example my disc has radius $r$ and the circle has radius $R$, then what does the equation representing a solid torus look like?

Comment: $$\left(R - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 \le r^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parametrization is helpful.

$$\rho= R+r \cos\phi\quad z= r \sin \phi \;$$

$$(\rho-R)^2+z^2=(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2 +z^2=r^2 $$

[image]

We can employ a variable along the normal to the circle section $ 0< rt<r $. Then the solid is the sum of many layers of expanding $r$ with $ 0<t<1 :$

$$\left(R - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 = r^2 t^2$$

Simply put, this  exterior surface is associated with the torus. If the inside of the toroidal surface is filled with a fluid then the volume is associated with the solid torus.

[Sections on Torus](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpiricSection.html) show some outer profiles of the layered solid when sectioned along a radius.

Parts of sections of such tori can be seen through oval annular rings  in lumber/plywood/studs around knots and single cut bent branches.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace $=$ with $<$ or $\le$.

Comment: You won't get an equation that way, only an inequality.

Comment: @MarkSapir Yes, and solids are defined by inequalities. E.g. the closed unit ball is given by $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$.

Comment: The OP wants an equation. At least this is the question.

Comment: I see that makes, but if I have a disc $u^2 + v^2 \le r$ and a circle $s^2 + t^2 = R$, then how can I find a map from $f(u,v,s,t)$ that gives the torus inequality in $R^3$?

Comment: @mathripper I'm not exactly sure what you want. If you take your torus equation and replace $=$ with $\le$, you get the same torus but solid, and still in $\mathbb R^3$. What else do you want?

Comment: What I mean is how to get the equation of the torus as a function of $u,v,s,t$ instead of $x,y,z$.

Comment: You can replace inequality $A<B$ by equation $A+r^2=B$. Note that it involves introducing a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you carefully read [the article that you have cited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_torus), you will notice that it says the solid torus is *homeomorphic to* the Cartesian product $S^1\times D^2.$ To say two things are homeomorphic is quite different from saying one is a construction of the other.

Notice that the same page tells you that the ordinary torus is homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1.$ If you can explain how this statement leads directly to the equation $\left(R - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 = r^2$ then I think you should write your own answer to your question about the solid torus.
I can only get to that equation by an indirect route shown below.

Since the solid torus is homeomorphic to $S^1\times D^2,$ however, that gives us some clues about how we might parameterize a solid torus. We can use the Cartesian product of a parameterization of a disk with a parameterization of a circle.

If we take a disk of radius $r$ as a region in a plane with Cartesian coordinates $(u,v)$ that satisfy $u^2 + v^2 \leq r^2,$ then the coordinates $(u,v)$ are a reasonable parameterization of the disk.

Cartesian coordinates are not a good parameterization of a circle. A better parameterization is the angle $\theta$ from some reference point on the circle.
So if we have a circle of radius $R$ in a plane with Cartesian coordinates
$(s,t),$ you can find any point on the circle by setting
\begin{align}
s &= R \cos\theta, \tag1\\
t &= R \sin\theta. \tag2\\
\end{align}
You can easily confirm that then $s^2 + t^2 = R^2.$ But when it comes to naming points on the circle, it is better to forget about the coordinates $(s,t)$ and just use $\theta$ as a coordinate (that is, just the angle component of polar coordinates).
This is because the circle is a one-dimensional object and should have just one coordinate.

We end up then with coordinates $(u,v,\theta)$ for the solid torus, with the "equation" (actually inequation)
$$ u^2 + v^2 \leq r^2.$$

If we write the coordinates in the sequence $(\theta,u,v)$ instead then we have parameterized the solid torus literally according to its homeomorphism with
$S^1\times D^2.$
That is, we have a parameter of $S^1$ concatenated with parameters of $D^2.$

If the $v$ axis of the disk at each $\theta$ is aligned with the axis of rotation of the torus and the positive $u$ direction is oriented away from the axis, then these are (almost) the cylindrical coordinates for a torus.
To get the usual cylindrical coordinates we merely need to set $\rho = u + R$ and then the inequation of the solid torus in cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,v,\theta)$ is
$$ (\rho - R)^2 + v^2 \leq r^2, $$
Note the similarity to the Cartesian equation for the torus,
setting $\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $v = z.$
Indeed, an equation for the torus (the boundary of the solid torus) in cylindrical coordinates is
$$ (\rho - R)^2 + v^2 = r^2 $$
or equivalently $(R - \rho)^2 + v^2 = r^2.$
The substitution $\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $v = z$ then turns this equation into the known equation
$\left(R - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 = r^2.$

If you insist on using Cartesian coordinates for both $S^1$ and $D^2$ in the Cartesian product $S^1\times D^2$ and applying those same coordinates to the solid torus,
keep in mind that for some objects, such as an arbitrary straight line in three-dimensional space with Cartesian coordinates, there is no single literal equation that describes the object.
The "equation" of the object may actually consist of several equations or a combination of equations and inequations; for example, the pair of equations
\begin{align}
x + y &= 2, \\
x - z &= 1 \\
\end{align}
describe a particular line in $(x,y,z)$ coordinates.

Using $s^2 + t^2 = R^2$ as an equation for a circle $S^1$
and $ u^2 + v^2 \leq r^2$ as an inequation for a disk $D^2,$
then an "equation" for the solid torus can simply be the combination of that equation and inequation,
\begin{align}
s^2 + t^2 &= R^2, \\
u^2 + v^2 &\leq  r^2. \\
\end{align}

As a description of a torus this leaves a lot to be desired.
For one thing, it gives us four coordinates, $(s,t,u,v)$ for an object that exists in three-dimensional space. We could take the view that the $s$ and $t$ specify a coordinate $\theta$ as the simultaneous solution of Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$.